# XML Deserialization from a StringReader Crashes

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I'm trying to build a very simple C# app to download the latest RUB-USD exchange rate.  www.cbr.ru provides a web service to pull the information from.  I am first calling the function to get the latest exchange rate date.  Then using that datetime to make the call to get the exchange rate on a particular date.

I'm able to pull the exchange rates XML and display it through StringReader.  I used Pasted XML as Classes to create a class using this XML.  When doing the coding, it seems to be working, as my rates variable autosuggests the expected attributes, i.e. rates.Vname, rates.Vcode, etc... however the program crashes (generic Windows error message - "NewExchangeRateService has stopped working") when it gets to Deserialization step.

Here's what I've got, some lines are simply part of my process and can obviously be ignored...

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    CBR.ru.DailyInfoSoapClient rublesClient = new DailyInfoSoapClient();
    DateTime lastRUB = rublesClient.GetLatestDateTime();
    MessageBox.Show(lastRUB.ToShortDateString());
    var RubRateXml = rublesClient.GetCursOnDateXML(lastRUB);
    DataSet RUBrate = rublesClient.GetCursOnDate(lastRUB);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(RUBrate.GetXml());
    richTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof (ValuteDataValuteCursOnDate));
    var rates = (ValuteDataValuteCursOnDate) xs.Deserialize(sr);
    MessageBox.Show(rates.Vname);
}
```

And the XML looks like:

```
<ValuteData>
  <ValuteCursOnDate>
    <Vname>Доллар США</Vname>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    <Vnom>1</Vnom>
    <Vcurs>53.1088</Vcurs>
    <Vcode>840</Vcode>
    <VchCode>USD</VchCode>
  </ValuteCursOnDate>
</ValuteData>
```

This generates the following classes:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class ValuteData
{

    private ValuteDataValuteCursOnDate[] valuteCursOnDateField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ValuteCursOnDate")]
    public ValuteDataValuteCursOnDate[] ValuteCursOnDate
    {
        get { return this.valuteCursOnDateField; }
        set { this.valuteCursOnDateField = value; }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ValuteDataValuteCursOnDate
{

    private string vnameField;

    private ushort vnomField;

    private decimal vcursField;

    private ushort vcodeField;

    private string vchCodeField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Vname
    {
        get { return this.vnameField; }
        set { this.vnameField = value; }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public ushort Vnom
    {
        get { return this.vnomField; }
        set { this.vnomField = value; }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal Vcurs
    {
        get { return this.vcursField; }
        set { this.vcursField = value; }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public ushort Vcode
    {
        get { return this.vcodeField; }
        set { this.vcodeField = value; }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string VchCode
    {
        get { return this.vchCodeField; }
        set { this.vchCodeField = value; }
    }
}
```

I'm sure this is extremely simple and I just have a misunderstanding somewhere on the use of the deserialization, so hopefully somebody can help me quickly.  If you'd like to take it one step further, I next will need to figure out how to pull the Vcurs where VchCode = USD (this is just a sample of the XML, there are lots of other rates included also)

Comment: "the program crashes" is not a specific enough problem description. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: And we don't have any idea about classes in your question, for ex what is `ValuteDataValuteCursOnDate` , any all other *magic* methods?

Comment: Sorry guys, let me elaborate: the crash is just "NewExchangeRateService has stopped working" "Do you want to send more information about the problem?"  I'll edit with a codeblock of my classes to explain ValuteDataValuteCursOnDate

Comment: Don't you think the class you have to use in deserialization is `ValuteData`? `new XmlSerializer(typeof (ValuteData));`

Comment: I think you are correct.  That seems to work also in the sense that the suggestions as I type my code appear as expected, but the program still crashes at the deserialization stage.

Comment: Do you also have an `XmlRoot("ValuteData")` somewhere? What do there rest of your partial classes contain? (any interfaces). And @L.B is correct it should be on the ValuteData (also valudate data should have the XmlRoot above it's class definition)

Comment: @Boone And you want to keep the exception message for  yourself? Since we are magicians, we can see it in our crystall ball

Comment: @Icepickle I updated my class definitions, did not realize that the top 2 lines got cut off.

Comment: @L.B The exception is 0xE0434352 - I'm sorry. I'm very new to this stuff and just figured out how to locate the exception code.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you don't do so much work in your constructor. Most of that work should be done in some sort of "load data" method, not in the constructor.

Comment: @Boone put a try/catch block  and read the exception. Come on, if you run your code in VS with *F5* , it will return the detailed exception.

Comment: @L.B Thank you for working with me, I apologize for my noobishness, problem now solved as I misused StringReader's functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `ReadToEnd`, and then try to deserialize from the same `StringReader`. But you have already read the entire reader.

Also, you should try something like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void LoadData()
{

    CBR.ru.DailyInfoSoapClient rublesClient = new DailyInfoSoapClient();
    DateTime lastRUB = rublesClient.GetLatestDateTime();
    // MessageBox.Show(lastRUB.ToShortDateString());
    var RubRateXml = rublesClient.GetCursOnDateXML(lastRUB);
    DataSet RUBrate = rublesClient.GetCursOnDate(lastRUB);
    string xml = RUBrate.GetXml();
    ValuteDataValuteCursOnDate rates;
    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof (ValuteDataValuteCursOnDate));
        rates = (ValuteDataValuteCursOnDate) xs.Deserialize(sr);
    }
    richTextBox1.Text = xml;
    // MessageBox.Show(rates.Vname);
}

var form = new Form1();
try
{
    form.LoadData();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Turns out it was more of a misunderstanding of StringReader than XmlSerializer.